# Change only the user of a file

Tags: linux, shell, syntax, opensuse, chown

I have a textfile with name `negin.txt` in `/home` and did the following:

*Right click → Properties → Permissions → Advanced Permissions → Add Entry → Named User* `user:wwwrun`

Is it possible to do this over the shell?

I tried `chown wwwrun /home/negin.txt` but got no result. What is wrong here?

[image: screenshot]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Add named user" function uses POSIX ACLs, which can be modified through command-line like this:

```
setfacl -m u:wwwrun:rw negin.txt
```

Comment: I'm so thankful to you,with this I have write and read access?

Comment: @Negin: You *already* have write and read access, since the file is *already* owned by the `wwwrun` user, and this `u:wwwrun:rw` ACL is pointless.

Comment: I appreciate you! you don't know how you helped me!!! thanks!!! thanks!!! very thanks! with your work I have this in advanced my goal was this I hope it will work in my install file too

Comment: well yes but by just calling chown wwwrun I had problem in properties no changes were done but with this facl yes it works

Comment: I tried it:D it works Nice and awesome:) I am so happy!

Answer (score 0):

Use `chown :wwwrun /home/negin.txt` to just set the group of the file.

Comment: Thanks I tried it tells me this in shell:chown: invalid group: `:wwwrun'

Comment: @Negin: because there is no such group?

Comment: then why I can set it by going to properties?

Comment: @Negin: True. I realise there is a colon in `:wwwrun` (in the error message). Maybe you typed one to much?

Comment: I tried chown:wwwrun as Aeron said and I tried chown wwwrun as I mentioned in my question both will have no affect  the command that I thaught tell me no error but when I then go to properties it still didn't add the wwwrun

Comment: I found something now when I go to peroperties it tells that user is now wwwrun it is not again the root but in the advanced option it didn't set it at all! I have a file for installing a software that I set the permissions by chown wwwrun for them but finally I must again set them manually cause affecting is none

Comment: @phresnel: `chown` accepts *`user`*, *`user:group`*, and *`:group`*.